# Error al compilar proyecto de OpenGl en VS2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows10, opengl

El error es el siguiente: Exception thrown at 0x00007FFC926DFCB1 (ucrtbased.dll) in OpenGL_window.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.

EL código en cuestión es el siguiente:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>


int main(void)
{
  GLFWwindow* window;

/* Initialize the library */
if (!glfwInit())
    return -1;

glewInit();

/* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
window = glfwCreateWindow(1920, 1080, "OpenGl Test", NULL, NULL);
if (!window)
{
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}

/* Make the window's context current */
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);


if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;

std::cout << glewGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;


/* Loop until the user closes the window */
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    /* Render here */ 
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f);
    glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.5f);
    glVertex2f(0.5f, -0.5f);
    glEnd();

    /* Swap front and back buffers */
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);

    /* Poll for and process events */
    glfwPollEvents();
}

glfwTerminate();
return 0;
}
```

El codigo este esta basado en un tutorial de OpenGL usando las librerías GLFW y glew, el tutorial en cuestion es: https://youtu.be/OR4fNpBjmq8 y https://youtu.be/H2E3yO0J7TM

Comment: Sabes lo que significa el error?

Comment: no lo se, la verdad

Answer (score 0):

Con glad se obtiene error al inicializarlo antes de establecer el contexto con `glfwMakeContextCurrent`.

Puede que el problema sea el mismo: que se llama `glewInit` antes de establecer el contexto con `glfwMakeContextCurrent`.

Si prestas atención está dos veces en el código.